# Why doesn't 'd0 extend the full width of the signal (as '0 does)?

Tags: system-verilog, modelsim

Using SystemVerilog and **Modelsim SE 2020.1**, I was surprised to see a behavior:

`bus_address` is a 64b signal `input logic [63:0] bus_address`

#### Using '0

`.bus_address         ('0),`

[image]

#### Using 'd0

`.bus_address         ('d0),`

[image]

#### Riviera-Pro 2020.04 (too buggy, we gave up using it and we are in a dispute with Aldec)

- `'d0`:

[image: rivierapro]

- `'0`:

[image: rivierapro_wrong]

### Investigation/Answer:

- **11.3.3 Using integer literals in expressions**: An unsized, based integer (e.g., 'd12 , 'sd12 )
- **5.7.1 Integer literal constants**:

> The number of bits that make up an unsized number (which is a simple
> decimal number or a number with a base specifier but no size
> specification) **shall be at least 32**. Unsized unsigned literal
> constants where the high-order bit is unknown ( X or x ) or
> three-state ( Z or z ) shall be extended to the size of the expression
> containing the literal constant.

That was tricky and I thought it would set `0` all the other bits as `'0` does.

I hope specs' authors will think more when defining such non-sense behaviors.

Comment: This behavior looks like a bug in the modelsim (and aldera) simulators. vcs and cadence do correct job. The value shouod have been zero-extended and fill all with 0 in both cases.

Comment: intrestengly enough modelsim changes behavior if you declare the port as `input var logic [63:0] `. There could be some misreadings in the standard.

Comment: Interesting. The standard specifies `shall be at least 32` then at least I can't complain, Modelsim SE 2020.1 is compliant. I wonder how Questa behaves.

Comment: Interestingly enough, **Aldec Riviera-Pro 2020.04** doesn't even support the `'0` as an input. (we gave up, we spent more time raising issues than using it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem has more with *port connections with mismatched sizes* than anything to do with numeric literals. It's just that the issue does not present itself when using the fill literals. This is because the fill literal automatically sizes itself eliminating port width mismatch.

The problem you see exists whether you use literals or other signals like in this example:

```
module top;
  wire [31:0] a = 0;
  dut d(a);
endmodule
module dut(input wire [63:0] p1);
  initial $strobeb(p1);
endmodule
```

According to section *23.3.3.7 Port connections with dissimilar net types (net and port collapsing)*, the nets `a` and `p1` might get merged into a single 64-bit net, but only the lower 32-bits remain driven, or `64'hzzzzzzzz00000000`.

If you change the port connection to a sized literal, `dut d(32'b0);`, you see the same behavior `64'hzzzzzzzz00000000`.

Now let's get back to the unsized numeric literal `'d0`. *Unsized* is a misnomer—all numbers have a size. It's just that the size is implicit and never the size you want it to be.  How many people write {'b1,'b0,'b1,'b0} thinking they've just wrote the same thing as `4'b1010`? This is actually illegal in the LRM, but some tools silently interpret it as `{32'b1,32'b0,32'b1,32'b0}`.

### Just never use an unsized literal.

Comment: Great answer as usual @dave_59! Sometimes I do it for unpacked arraays: `'{'d0,'d1, 'd2}`. *never use an unsized literal*.. well, it's a pity, I found them very useful when I want to stay generic. Forced to stop using a useful features because tools don't process them.

Comment: I do not see how this paragraph in the standard can justify the behavior shown by the modelsim. There is no word about different net sizes and nothing about variables or literal constants which are not nets.

Comment: @Serge, Sorry I tried but could not find a clearer explanation in the LRM. I know this section has gone through a lot of editing to accommodate SystemVerilog enhancements, so some of it might have been lost. But 3 out of 4 commercial simulators on EDAplayground produce the same results for the testcase I show.

Comment: actually synopsys and cadence in eda playground do not agree with mentor and aldec  on this  :-)

Comment: try this: `dut d2('d0);`